# ComboBox throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when a DataAdapter is filled

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, combobox

In some fairly mature software, I have a designer-generated single-table DataSet that I recently had to re-create after Visual Studio had a bit of a meltdown. It's a simple enough customer DataSet that fetches an ID column, customer name and some contact details.

There is a particular UserControl in the software that presents users with a dropdown list of all of these customers, via a ComboBox. This has been databound to the DataSet via the Designer. This creates `CustomerDataSet` and `CustomerTableAdapter` objects on my UserControl, and a `CustomerBindingSource` on my `cboCustomer` ComboBox.

Since re-creating the DataSet, however, loading the UserControl calls

```
Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerDataSet.customer)
```

Which calls the designer-generated routine:

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0"), _
Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter"), _
Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Fill, True)> _
Public Overridable Overloads Function Fill(ByVal dataTable As CustomerDataSet.customerDataTable) As Integer
    Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
    If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = True) Then
        dataTable.Clear()
    End If
    Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

When the code hits the line:

```
Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
```

the `cboCustomer` throws an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
    HResult=-2146233086
    Message=InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex
    ParamName=SelectedIndex
    Source=System.Windows.Forms
    StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
    InnerException:
```

However, if I quickwatch the result of `Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)` the exception is not thrown and the program works as normal.

I can't see what has changed to make the program start crashing at this point (obviously the DataSet, but I can't see which change in particular). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an idea, but I have an advice. Start using a version control tool (git is a common choice). You shouldn't have to guess what has changed, you should be able to know with complete certainty.

Comment: We're using git. It's a change to designer-generated code, and there's hundreds of lines of changes (presumably) because the original DataSet was generated in an earlier version of Visual Studio. I can *see* the changes, but I won't have any idea what they are without trudging through the designer-generated code-swamp for the next three days. Hence I'm hoping someone will recognise the issue and get me out of doing that.

Comment: That's horrible. At least you've done what you should've done to give yourself a good chance - by sometimes that's not enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is horrible for performance, but you could `cboCustomer.DataSource = Nothing` before filling then after filling `cboCustomer.DataSource = dataTable`

Comment: Well, it stops the crashing but I'll hold out a little while longer before marking that as a proper answer, if you don't mind. Oddly, setting `CustomerBindingSource.DataSource` to `Nothing` will cause the ComboBox to throw the same exception when I set the DataSource back to the DataTable, after filling. That surprised me.

Comment: I thought it might, in that case then I would prevent it from trying to do what ever it is doing in the `cboCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged` sub because that is probably what is causing the issues all together. I usually used a Boolean on my forms to stop if from going further than the check in the `SelectedIndexChanged` sub

Comment: Strangely enough, I don't have any code for that. I've got a handler for `SelectedValueChanged`, but that isn't hit during the `Fill` method, and doesn't seem to cause the crash.

Comment: 4.5 at the moment, but I would think that this was originally written under framework 3.

Comment: I used 3.5 and for some reason it always hits the `SelectedIndexChanged` sub whenever there is a change in the `DataSource`  That is why I used a Boolean.